# Make use of event handler in React Component for TSX tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, tsx

Is there a way to make an event handler defined within a React Component accessible in an HTML-like tag? What I mean is something like:

```
<MyComp param1="abc" param2="def" onDoSomething={this.someMethod} />
```

My goal is to define `onDoSomething`, but currently I only know how to create params such as `param1` and `param2`.

```
export interface MyCompProps {
    param1: string;
    param2: string;
}

export interface DoSomethingEvent {
    someParam: string;
}

export class MyComp extends React.Component<MyCompProps, {}> {
    private doSomethingDispatcher = new EventDispatcher<DoSomethingEvent>();

    public onDoSomething(handler: Handler<DoSomethingEvent>) {
        this.doSomethingDispatcher.register(handler);
    }

    private fireDoSomething(param: string) {
        this.doSomethingDispatcher.fire({someParam: param});
    }
}
```

How can I make the event handler `onDoSomething` accessible via TSX, similar to making use of the `onClick` event?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but just simply include `onDoSomething` as another member in `MyCompProps`? `onDoSomething: (Handler<DoSomethingEvent>) => void;`

Comment: @miqh Yes, that's what I thought of, by adding something to `MyCompProps` such as `onDoSomething: (Handler<PageChangedEvent>);`. But when running `fireDoSomething` nothing happens on the other side. The method `someMethod()` is not triggered. Adding `onDoSomething: (Handler<DoSomethingEvent>) => void;` results in an error `[ts] ";" expected. [1005]`. Any idea how else to get this running?

Comment: Ah, my bad—that's because I forgot to include the argument name inside the function interface member. Including one should get you by. `(handler: Handler<DoSomethingEvent>) => void;`. Also, noticed your other comment below about how `someMethod()` is bound. I don't think you shouldn't be using `()` as this will prematurely invoke the method and bind the method result, not the method, to the prop.

Comment: @miqh Ok, it compiles now without errors when adding to `MyCompProps` the `onDoSomething: (handler: Handler<DoSomethingEvent>) => void;`. On the parent side the `<MyComp param1="abc" param2="def" onDoSomething={this.someMethod} />` also compiles, but the method `someMethod` is never triggered. Do I have to connect the event handler somewhere in the props?

Comment: @miqh Ok, I got it running. The syntax is a bit different than expected. Added `onDoSomething: (someParamName: string) => void;` to `MyCompProps`. Then to trigger that I added `this.props.onDoSomething("some message");` to the method `fireDoSomething`. Works like a charm when one does it right. Thanks again lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running into issues as you are not currently providing a function to onDoSomething, but the returned result:

```
<MyComp param1="abc" param2="def" onDoSomething={this.someMethod()} />
```

should be

```
<MyComp param1="abc" param2="def" onDoSomething={this.someMethod} />
```

Comment: If I understand you right, the difference is just `()`, which is not the issue in this post as it just means *no params*. The question is how to achieve the event handling similar to `<button onClick={this.myMethod()}>Click me</button>`.

Comment: Updated the above post avoiding `()`.